A value of type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget
I'm attempting to implement the showCupertinoModalPopup() form the cupertino library of Flutter for my flutter app. I'm getting the said error when I use a return showCupertinoModalPopup() from a Widget build (BuildContext context).

I intend to show a cupertino modal popup which contains the
cupertinoactionsheet with options for the user to choose from and pop
out after selection. While cupertinoactionsheet itself works since it
is a widget, when I attempt to wrap it inside the cupertino modal
popup , for a true IOS style UI, I get
the said error.

Here is my code snippet :


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return showCupertinoModalPopup(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => CupertinoActionSheet(
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              onPressed: ({int index = 0}) {
                VideosSoundSetting newType = allVideosSoundSettings[index];
                widget.onTypeChanged(newType);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18),
                'Enabled',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
              child: const Text(
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 18),
                'Disabled',
              ),
              onPressed: ({int index = 1}) {
                VideosSoundSetting newType = allVideosSoundSettings[index];
                widget.onTypeChanged(newType);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
        cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          isDefaultAction: true,
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const KNText(
            'Cancel',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I followed the example from this link and implemented on similar lines for my case.
Flutter - CupertinoActionSheet / CupertinoActionSheetAction background color different on-device than in simulator
I've spent quite a lot of time figuring this out and unable the best way to do it. Assistance required.

The error is pretty clear in this case, the build function of a Widget needs to return another Widget. You are returning the result of showCupertinoModalPopup(), which according to the doc (and error message), returns a Future.
What I think you want to do instead is not call showCupertinoModalPopup() from a build method, but in response to some action (like in a button's onPress listener) or whatever other trigger you are expecting to cause the popup to open.

Ok. Will work on similar lines. Thank you.

Sounds good. If you want, you can post where you are hoping to trigger the pop up from to give some more context for us to provide a more complete answer as well.

Hi did solve it finally. Thank you for helping me out.

Hi again. As an extension to the above question , could you pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78382640/cupertinoactionsheetaction-onpressed-to-trigger-a-loading-indicator-followed-by
