CupertinoActionSheetAction onPressed to trigger a loading indicator followed by checkmark with a delay
I'm using a CupertinoModalPopup with a CupertinoActionSheet widget to display a set of options for the user to choose from.

I intend to show a circular loading indicator followed by a checkmark(tick) to
give the user the impression that he has clicked the option and it is
saved after popping out using Navingator.pop(context).
First , I'm attempting to do this with a delay of 100milliseconds using
Future.delayed after clicking onPressed
using only a Widget that displays a circular loading indicator for now. But it isn't working.

Here is my code to better explain what I'm doing. Only relevant code is published.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return CupertinoActionSheet(
        title: KNText(
          style: TextStyle(color: primaryTextColor),
          'Video sound settings',
        ),
        message: KNText(
          style: TextStyle(color: primaryTextColor),
          'Please choose from an option below :',
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
              color: primaryColor,
              child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                onPressed: ({int index = 0}) async {
                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                    setState(() {
                      VideosSoundSetting newType =
                          allVideosSoundSettings[index];
                      widget.onTypeChanged(newType);
                      _setEnabledInProgress(true);

                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                    setState(() {
                      _enabledInProgress = false;
                    });
                  });
                },

A circular loading indicator(delay : 100 milliseconds) followed by a checkmark tick(delay:50 milliseconds) will appear for a brief time after clicking on either option to give the user an impression that its a success. Currently , only circular loading indicator is configured below.
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 153.0),
                      child: KNText(
                        style: TextStyle(color: primaryTextColor),
                        'Enabled',
                      ),
                    ),
                    _enabledInProgress
                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : Container()
                  ],
                ),
              )),
          Container(
              color: primaryColor,
              child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(

// A circular loading indicator(delay : 100 milliseconds) followed by a checkmark tick(delay:50 milliseconds) will appear for a brief time after clicking on either option to give the user an impression that its a success. Currently , only circular loading indicator is configured below.
                onPressed: ({int index = 0}) async {
                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
                    setState(() {
                      VideosSoundSetting newType =
                          allVideosSoundSettings[index];
                      widget.onTypeChanged(newType);
                      _setEnabledInProgress(true);

                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                    setState(() {
                      _enabledInProgress = false;
                    });
                  });
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150.0),
                      child: KNText(
                        style: TextStyle(color: primaryTextColor),
                        'Disabled',
                      ),
                    ),
                    _enabledInProgress
                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                        : Container()
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ],
        cancelButton: Container(
          color: primaryColor,
          child: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Row(children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 155.0),
                child: KNText(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1.0),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                  'Cancel',
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ));
   }     
    void _setEnabledInProgress(bool enabledInProgress) {
    _enabledInProgress = enabledInProgress;
  }      

What is working :

The options and selection does work with a delay in milliseconds as specified

What doesn't :

The circular progress indicator at the very end of 'Enabled' and Disabled actions doesn't appear. After fixing the circular progress indicator with a delayed duration, I intend to call a checkmark tick widget  after which the checkmark should appear and popout from the widget itself,.

If I could be pointed in the right direction of how best to achieve the above goal of

Loading indicator with a delay of 100 milliseconds.
Checkmark Tick appearing immediately after the loading indicator in the same place and popping out after 50 milliseconds

EDIT as on 29-04-2024
Based on the guidance received from @anqit in the comments below, I did manage to somewhat make some progress. have updated the code to reflect the changes.

You're creating the ListTile for the check mark in setState(), but setState() doesn't return anything or actually insert anything into the Widget tree. You're basically just creating the element and then throwing it away.

Oh. Damn my ignorance. A return statement is missing I recon ?

Could you help with the code based on the loading indicator and checkmark that I'm trying to implement?

no, it's not a return statement that's missing, setState() takes a void callback, and so doesn't return anything. setState is used to do something (update a widget's state and trigger a rebuild), not put widgets in the widget tree. From this and your other question, I think it would be helpful for you if you spent some time understanding the difference between when flutter does a thing vs when it shows a thing. I can try to throw something together if I find some time.

Understood. Will try working in that direction.

Hi again. Made edits to the code based on your guidance. I believe , i'm missing something since it isn't working.

Summary:

The StatefulBuilder widgets may not be required, as the BuildContext may come from your custom widget. The ElevatedButton serves as an example of launching the CupertinoActionSheet, which can be substituted with whatever method you are using. Note that I didn't make use of custom widgets such as KNText. The two parts to your question to my understanding are how to show loading, and how to show a checkmark after selection and loading. Note I set the delay for loading to 1000ms, so you can see the loading longer in the example.


Loading Summary

The loading CircularProgressIndicator is shown by roughly following the below steps. ref _showLoading function in the code below.

call showDialog
have showDialog return a CircularProgressIndicator
run Future.delayed (in production a network call?)
call Navigator.pop to close the loading dialog

Checkmark Summary:

The checkmark can be shown in many ways, in this case I made use of Visibility to hide and show the checkmarks based on the values in the Map named selected in the code below. The values in selected are updated when the buttons in the modal are pressed (after loading is done). The rough process is as follows

enable or disable button pressed
show loading
loading done
update values in selected based on which button was pressed
rebuild, because setState was called. When building the checkmarks are shown based on the values in selected.


Button:




Modal:




Loading:




Check changed after loading



Code:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  // used to indicate which option is selected
  Map<String, bool> selected = {
    "enabled": true,
    "disabled": false,
  };

  // shows the loading indicator
  Future<void> _showLoading({
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    // show dialog overlay with just a progress indicator
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );

    // run delay - assume swapping for some kind of network call
    // on delay done pop loading dialog
    await Future.delayed(
      const Duration(
        milliseconds: 1000,
      ),
      () {
        Navigator.pop(
          context,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) => Center(
            // button to trigger modal
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text(
                "Click to test",
              ),
              onPressed: () => showCupertinoModalPopup(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext modalContext) {
                  /*
                    Rough example begins
                  */
                  return StatefulBuilder(
                    builder: (context, setState) => CupertinoActionSheet(
                      title: const Text(
                        "Video sound settings",
                      ),
                      message: const Text(
                        "Please choose from an option below :",
                      ),
                      actions: [
                        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                          onPressed: ({
                            int index = 0,
                          }) async {
                            // show loading, and wait till function done
                            await _showLoading(
                              context: context,
                            );

                            // tell flutter to build, check will be shown based on values set on next build
                            setState(
                              () {
                                selected["enabled"] = true;
                                selected["disabled"] = false;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                "Enabled",
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: selected["enabled"]!,
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.check,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                          onPressed: ({
                            int index = 0,
                          }) async {
                            await _showLoading(
                              context: context,
                            );

                            // opposite values
                            setState(
                              () {
                                selected["enabled"] = false;
                                selected["disabled"] = true;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                "Disabled",
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: selected["disabled"]!,
                                child: const Icon(
                                  Icons.check,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                        isDefaultAction: true,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(
                            context,
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "Cancel",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Updated code
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  // used to indicate which option is selected
  Map<String, bool> selected = {
    "enabled": true,
    "disabled": false,
  };

  // if true show loading
  bool loadingFlag = false;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState) => Center(
            // button to trigger modal
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text(
                "Click to test",
              ),
              onPressed: () => showCupertinoModalPopup(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext modalContext) {
                  /*
                    Rough example begins
                  */
                  return StatefulBuilder(
                    builder: (context, setState) => CupertinoActionSheet(
                      title: const Text(
                        "Video sound settings",
                      ),
                      message: const Text(
                        "Please choose from an option below :",
                      ),
                      actions: [
                        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                          onPressed: ({
                            int index = 0,
                          }) async {

                            // update flags and set loading flag, then build
                            setState(
                              () {
                                selected["enabled"] = true;
                                selected["disabled"] = false;
                                loadingFlag = true;
                              },
                            );

                            // wait for delay, change loading flag, then build
                            await Future.delayed(
                              const Duration(
                                milliseconds: 1000,
                              ),
                              () {
                                setState(
                                  () {
                                    loadingFlag = false;
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                "Enabled",
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: selected["enabled"]!,
                                // check loading flag to determine if should show loading or check
                                child: loadingFlag
                                    ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                                    : const Icon(
                                        Icons.check,
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                          onPressed: ({
                            int index = 0,
                          }) async {
                            // opposite enable disable
                            setState(
                              () {
                                selected["enabled"] = false;
                                selected["disabled"] = true;
                                loadingFlag = true;
                              },
                            );

                            await Future.delayed(
                              const Duration(
                                milliseconds: 1000,
                              ),
                              () {
                                setState(
                                  () {
                                    loadingFlag = false;
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                "Disabled",
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: selected["disabled"]!,
                                child: loadingFlag
                                    ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                                    : const Icon(
                                        Icons.check,
                                      ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                      cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                        isDefaultAction: true,
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(
                            context,
                          );
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          "Cancel",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}



Thanks for the detailed answer. Only thing is the loading indicator I intended to show in the same place as the the checkmark. so OnPressed --> shows a tiny loading indicator for a short time and then a checkmark appears immediately in its place. I would still like to thank you for your help here in taking time to write a detailed answer.

@Earthling, I added another version below, which shows the loading where the checkbox is supposed to go.

Just a small question here. The checkmark immediately appears and disappears with Navingator.onPop(). There isn't a delay for the same. I intended to show the checkmark for a small duration and then pop out.

@Earthling if you want to hide the check icon change the values in selected in a setState. If the check goes to default after a pop, the issue is related to the way you are doing state management in your app.

Hi. figured it out with a delay. Thank you for all your assistance.

Hi again. My new question. Could you take time to help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78542851/imagepicker-ontap-trigger-makes-use-of-2-calls-onpressed-and-ontap-need-t
