ImagePicker onTap trigger makes use of 2 calls : OnPressed() and onTap(). Need to make it a single call
I have 2 Widget functions which while initiating onPressed() is supposed to show a imagepicker() using a CupertinoActionsheet with Actions to choose an image from Gallery/Camera.
The CupertinoActionSheet and the actions are part of _imagePickerService.pickImage().
Widget _buildUserAvatar() {
var _onPressed = () {
_showImageBottomSheet(imageType: ImageType.avatar);
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: _onPressed,
  child: const Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              size: 20,));
};}

Widget _buildUserProfileCover() {
var _onPressed = () {
_showImageBottomSheet(imageType: ImageType.cover);
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: _onPressed,
  child: const Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              size: 20,));
};}



Future<void> _showImageBottomSheet({required ImageType imageType}) async {
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        List<Widget> listActions = [
          Expanded(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                try {
                  var image = await _imagePickerService.pickImage(
                      imageType: imageType, context: context);

                  _onUserImageSelected(image: image, imageType: imageType);
                } on FileTooLargeException catch (e) {
                  int limit = e.getLimitInMB();
                  if (context.mounted) {
                    toastService.error(
                        message: _localizationService
                            .user__edit_profile_pick_image_error_too_large(
                                limit),
                        context: context);
                  }
                }
                if (context.mounted) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ];

        switch (imageType) {
          case ImageType.cover:
            if (_coverUrl != null || _coverFile != null) {
              listActions.add(CupertinoActionSheet());
            }
          case ImageType.avatar:
            if (_avatarUrl != null || _avatarFile != null) {
              listActions.add(CupertinoActionSheet());
            }
          default:
            throw 'Unhandled imageType';
        }

        return Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: listActions);
      });
}



Unfortunately, I had to used Gesture detector to trigger a onTap to show the CupertinoActionSheet with its options which work fine. The previous onPressed triggers showModalBottomSheet() which again needs to be Tapped using GestureDetector to open up the options.
Note : The switch() is used to clear the Avatar or Cover File based on whether it exists or not. It is yet to be coded and not important now.
Need help to use a single Onpressed to call The Imagepicker().
